# In Jenkins, how do I get the display name of a build given it's number?

Tags: jenkins

I have a project in Jenkins (lets call 'Project B') which copies artifacts from another project ('Project A') and repackages them. To copy the artifacts I'm using the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

In Project A I am using the [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) to set a display name for our build; and would like to do the same in Project B.

Since Project B is just a re-packaging of Project A's artifacts I would like them to share the same display name. As far as I can tell, Copy Artifact Plugin only gives me a variable for the build number. It would be ideal to have a variable with the build display name of Project A so I can assign it as the build display name for Project B.

**Question:**
How can I get the display name of a build on another project with the build number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using groovy, you can a `Execute sustem Groovy Script`.

Inside this script, you can access the current build via `build`, more importantly you have access the jenkins instance via `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance`.

This will give you access to the majority of stuff in jenkins, including the list of jobs via in `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItems()` which you can search and get builds for each job.